Tagging Math environment
I want to use
\[ \] instead of \begin{equation} ... \end{equation} for one-lined equations or definitions.
My problem now is that in the equation environment I automatically get a tag (number), which I do not get for the math environment. Is there any way to connect a \tag{} in the math mode environment to the  \tag{} in the equation environment?
I obviously do not want to change the entire math environment command since then I always get a tag which might be unwanted at some point.

In your previous question, you promised that the next time you would add a MWE :(

Use equation and equation*, then it is easy to switch between numbered and unnumbered

I thought about adding one but I did not know how I should add one in this scenario?? :( I am sorry but I do not see any information that where a code is neccessary...

you shouldn't change \[ but as far as a MWE is concerned it really helps anyone planning an answer to have a basic example document where you describe the wished outcome, and lets people test answers

in particular what do you mean by "connect" here?  \tag  works in \[ in exactly the same way as it works in \begin{equation} already, so what do you want to change in \documentclass{article} \usepackage{amsmath} \begin{document} \[a=b\tag{foo}\] \begin{equation}   x=y\tag{bar} \end{equation} \end{document} ?

Hmm.. yes I get that, I just don‘t see the need here. But whatever I will include it next time even though I don‘t understand it.
The equation environment gives me automically a number, so I do not need to put a tag anywhere. Yet, in the math environment if I were to need a tag I must put a number in myself. So if I change anything in the code the number does not change with it. I would need the number to change too.

About usefulness of MWE's, just a few hints: (A) LaTeX is complex, and problems range from forgotten things to spoiled code. (B) like in novels: show, don't tell. (C) code will come up anyway, see e.g. @DavidCarlisle s comment. (D) by providing compilable code you enable us to try and modify it for the better. (E) if you don't need to post code, it probably can be answered by reading some of the books introducing LaTeX - which you certainly read or consult, did you?  (F) you avoid comment avalances like this one. (G) Preparing code can be half the answer. // Just to mention a few

you did not mention the automatic equation numbering in your question. You said you wanted the use of \tag to be connected. \tag is a perfectly valid amsmath command that works in equation  environments and elsewhere, how is anyone supposed to guess by \tag you were refering to equation environments that do not use \tag ?  You should edit the question here not just make an example in your next question
